# Rotating a transparent png file with ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, image-manipulation, imagemagick-convert

I've a transparent png file with 100x100 size containing some text, like:

```
convert -size 100x100 -font Courier -pointsize 40 -draw 'text 10,40 "pie"' xc:transparent a.png
```

and an empty blue backgrounded bottom.jpg:

```
convert -size 30x30 xc:blue bottom.jpg
```

. I'd like to put the a.png file onto bottom.jpg file doing some resizing this way:

```
convert bottom.jpg \( a.png -resize 25% -geometry +2+1 \) -composite -matte -resize 300 b.jpg
```

which works well. And I need to rotate the text from the a.png image, however my command does not work that well:

```
convert bottom.jpg \( a.png -resize 25% -geometry +2+1 -rotate 40% \) -composite -matte -resize 300 brotated.jpg
```

.

How can I create the brotated.jpg in a way that it does not have that white "rest part" which is coming from the rotation? I think I need to preserve the alpha (on), but it does not work with this command.

All example files can be found here:

http://87.229.108.143/files/stack_question_23THj/2/

.

Answer (score 0):

As i experienced i just need to add a **-background none** switch like this:

```
convert -background none bottom.jpg \( a.png -resize 25% -geometry +2+1 -rotate 40% \) -composite -matte -resize 300 brotated.jpg
```